# Information Schema Table Description / Comment

Tags: php, mysql, comments, information-schema

What is the query code to extract the Table Comment/Description?
To get column descriptions is easy.  Is there a URL or list of the various queries and options you can perform on Information schema and their applicable column-names options?

To clarify:

```
$sql = "SELECT TABLE_COMMENT FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMN_NAME WHERE `TABLE_SCHEMA` = '$dbnm' AND TABLE_NAME = '$tbl_nm' LIMIT 1";
```

This turns out nothing (obviously);
I need to pull out an exact description of the table in question, individually
not show all the information on a particular table.

I also need it in a form I can run an SQL query on it
to make it usable....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
... FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMN_NAME ...
```

There is no such table called `COLUMN_NAME` in the information_schema.

If you want to get table comments, use this query:

```
$sql = "SELECT TABLE_COMMENT FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES 
    WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = '$dbnm' AND TABLE_NAME = '$tbl_nm'";
```

If you want reference documentation for the tables in the information schema and their columns try: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/information-schema.html

Or else view it yourself:

```
mysql> SHOW TABLES FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA;
mysql> DESC INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES;
```